# android stream real time video to streaming server

Tags: android, youtube, video-streaming, rtsp, wowza

I am trying to develop a half duplex chat application where one android device will capture video from cam and send this real time video stream to server.
Thereafter, another android device is capturing the same video stream from the streaming server and rendering the video on screen.

I successfully did this using WebRTC API, Vitamio API and wowza streaming server.

But, this method is resulting in a very poor video quality at receiver's end with poor video quality and huge latency even on fast working LAN. Moreover the device heatup problem is also comming into existance.

Please tell me any other method to achieve the same.
Does youtube provide any facility to broadcast the real time video stream.
Is there any other free service that enables us sending video stream to the server from android device (as i have done in my application).

Comment: There are tools like Wowza Server which can get a source video stream and put it on the output of the server for other clients. I guess VLC can do this too, via File-->Stream menu, an then putting the RTSP video stream address from your spyDroid based app. But I have not tested it personally.The idea might help you.

Comment: both if the two things you suggested, i have already implemented both of them. By question is is there any online service provider of video broadcasting at real time. (eg; skype, hangouts)... If yes then how. Impementation should be in android-programming.

Comment: Did you try apprtc demo?, It is possible to stream from one android to another using webrtc.

Comment: Yes, i have tried VLC Streaming, WOWZA server, Vitamio, WebRTC, QuickBlox. Everything  i have tried. Everything is working. But issue is only that device is getting heatup and app hangs after 20min of working. I need any online service for video streaming that i can use and stream my real-time video to cloud.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: Yes, there are many options now to implement real-time communications with the best performance and good network bandwidth adaptability.